# Mongo group command with missing keys

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo as a tick database where I periodically put data in with timestamps. Later I use this data to query statistics about the system.

I have a collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-16T03:58:58.152Z"),
    "min": 4,
    "max": 25
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-18T03:48:58.152Z"),
    "min": 3,
    "max": 8
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-18T03:48:58.152Z"),
    "min": 8,
    "max": 12
  }
]
```

I use the `group` command to group all documents by day.

```
db.stats.group({
    keyf: function (doc) {
        var date = new Date(doc.date);
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);    
        return { date: date };
    },
    reduce: function (curr, result) {
        result.max = Math.max(curr.max, result.max || 0);
        result.min = Math.min(curr.min, result.min || 0);
    },
    initial: {}
});
```

This gives me the result of:

```
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-16T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "min": 4,
    "max": 25
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-18T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "min": 3,
    "max": 12
  }
]
```

The problem for me is that since there was no entries on 2014-06-17 I need to somehow create one with `min: 0 and max: 0` so the result should look like:

```
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-16T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "min": 4,
    "max": 25
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-17T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2014-06-18T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "min": 3,
    "max": 12
  }
]
```

If I could somehow give the group command an array of dates as keys this could work. If this possible in Mongo?

Comment: I had similar problem, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039406/skipped-count-0-in-aggregate-function?noredirect=1#comment38963506_25039406

Answer (score 2):

> If I could somehow give the group command an array of dates as keys this could work. If this possible in Mongo?

You can't `group()` on data that doesn't exist, so you will have to insert some data for each day.

Effectively the approach you want to take is [pre-aggregating data](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) in order to ensure you have a sample for every day in your date range.

> The problem for me is that since there was no entries on 2014-06-17 I need to somehow create one with min: 0 and max: 0

Given you are calculating a daily min/max, one approach would be to take advantage of the new [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/) and [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) update operators in MongoDB 2.6 and upsert values into a daily collection.

Since you only want to have the mix/max value per day, a daily document could look like:

```
{
    "date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0
}
```

Note: I've chosen to format date as an ISO8601-ish string for clarity in this example, but you could also use a `Date` field if you prefer. A full BSON `Date` will include time and timezone information, so you'll need to be sure to truncate appropriately for your queries/updates.

Here's an example in the `mongo` shell using [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) (for convenient date manipulation) to iterate a range of dates and add any missing values:

```
var nextDate = moment("2014-06-01");
var lastDate = moment("2014-07-31");

while (nextDate <= lastDate) { 
    db.daily.findAndModify({
        query: {
            date: nextDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        },
        update: {
            $max: { min: 0, max: 0 },
        },
        upsert: true
    });
    nextDate.add(1, 'day');
}
```

Since this is using an `upsert` flag:

- daily documents that don't exist will be inserted with default min/max values of 0
- daily documents that do exist will be updated with the $max of their existing `min` and `max` field values (i.e. existing values will be preserved)

You could use the same update query to maintain your daily min/max as new data is inserted (by providing the current values for min/max instead of `0`), or calculate the daily min/max from the original samples using a sort order:

```
// Daily minimum for 2014-06-18 (assuming ticks are using standard `Date` fields)
db.ticks.find(

    // query criteria
    { date: { $gte: ISODate("2014-06-18"), $lt: ISODate("2014-06-19") } },

    // projection
    { min: 1, _id: 0 }

).sort({min: 1}).limit(1)
```

.

```
// Daily maximum for 2014-06-18
db.ticks.find(

    // query criteria
    { date: { $gte: ISODate("2014-06-18"), $lt: ISODate("2014-06-19") } },

    // projection
    { max: 1, _id: 0 }

).sort({max: -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: This would work if I only queried per day however I have "zoom levels" for my data. You could possibly look into the depth of a minute. Guess my best bet is to do some data manipulation after the query.

Comment: @RobFox: FYI, the [Pre-Aggregated Reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) page I linked includes some typical approaches for time series data at different granularities. If a pre-aggregated approach doesn't suit your use case, you will have to do some data manipulation in your application code to fill in the gaps when you present the data.