# skipped count 0 in aggregate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm stuck on this for couple of days. I'm trying to get the `count: 0` where there is no documents in the given time period. This is the aggregate function I'm using at the moment:

```
var getCount = function(timeBlock, start, end, cb) {

    Document.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            time: {
                $gte: new Date(start),
                $lt: new Date(end)
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: 1,
            delta: { $subtract: [
                new Date(end),
                '$time'
            ]}
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: 1,
            delta: { $subtract: [
                "$delta",
                { $mod: [
                    "$delta",
                    timeBlock
                ]}
            ]}
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $subtract: [
                end,
                "$delta"
            ]},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: "$_id",
            count: 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    },

    {
        $sort: {
            time: 1
        }

    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            cb(null, results)
        }
    })
}
```

I tried using `$cond`, but with no luck

Comment: This is definitely a hard one since unlike in SQL where you can create a range separately to the table data and 0 it out you cannot in MongoDB, it runs according to documents and there is currently no way to do this cleanly, or even at all as far as I know. What stops you from just returning 0 when you go to place this in your interface, i.e. chart?

Comment: A similar question was asked a few days ago: [Mongo group command with missing keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979819/). Your solution of post-processing results also works, but if you are reporting on time series data there might be more efficient ways to model the data.

Comment: @Stennie thank you! that sounds like another approach, although I don't think it will work with my example, because I'd like to get `count: 0` when document doesn't exist. I cannot pre-insert a document, because the `count` will be `1`. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @knowbody: I was thinking more along the lines of pre-aggregating your counts (i.e. if you have consistent time series buckets, you could create defaults with a min value of 0 that can be incremented). If you're grouping to count I don't think there's a way to aggregate a count of 0 without contortions (i.e. more work than your "hacky" solution).

Comment: @Stennie thanks again. for now I leave it as it is. but might consider your solution later on. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The group stage is producing documents based on grouping on your given _id and counting the number of documents from the previous stage that end up in the group. Hence, a count of zero would be the result of a document being created from 0 input documents belonging to the group. Thinking about it this way, it's clear that there's no way the aggregation pipeline can do this for you. It doesn't know what all of the "missing" time periods are and it can't invent the appropriate documents out of thin air. Reapplying your extra knowledge about the missing time periods to complete the picture at the end seems like a reasonable solution (not "hacky") if you need to have an explicit count of 0 for empty time periods.

Comment: thank you! that was my conclusion after couple of hours of playing around with it. although I was hoping I missed something and that there is the way. +1

Answer (score 1):

Though it has already been said the best thing to do here is "merge" your results post process rather than expect "keys" that do not exist to appear or to issue multiple queries with explicit keys that are possibly not going to aggregate results and combine them.

What has not already been said is how you actually do this, so I'll give you a MongoDB "thinking" kind of way to collect your results.

As a quick disclaimer, you could possibly employ much the same approach by "seeding" empty keys for each interval using mapReduce, or possibly even altering your data so that there is always an empty value within each possible block. Those approaches seem basically "hacky" and in the mapReduce case is not going to provide the best performance or muliple results.

What I would suggest is that working with collection results for the MongoDB brain can be made simple. There is a neat little solution called [neDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), which is billed as a kind of SQL Lite for MongoDB. It supports a subset of functionality and is therefore perfect for "in memory" manipulation of results with a MongoDB mindset:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var documentSchema = new Schema({
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Document = mongoose.model( "Document", documentSchema );


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var getCount = function(timeBlock, start, end, callback) {

  async.waterfall(
    [

      // Fill a blank series
      function(callback) {

        var db = new DataStore();

        var current = start;

        async.whilst(
          function() { return current < end },
          function(callback) {
            var delta = end - current;
            db.insert({ "_id": end - delta, "count": 0 },function(err,doc) {
              //console.log( doc );
              current += timeBlock;
              callback(err);
            });
          },
          function(err) {
            callback(err,db);
          }
        );
      },

      // Get data and update
      function(db,callback) {

        var cursor = Document.collection.aggregate(
          [
            // Match documents
            { "$match": {
              "time": {
                "$gte": new Date(start),
                "$lt": new Date(end)
              }
            }},

            // Group. 1 step and less hacky
            { "$group": {
              "_id": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "delta": {
                      "$subtract": [
                        { "$subtract": [ new Date(end), "$time" ] },
                        { "$mod": [
                          { "$subtract": [ new Date(end), "$time" ] },
                          timeBlock
                        ]}
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "in": { "$subtract": [ end, "$$delta" ] }
                }
              },
              "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }}
          ],
          { "cursor": { "batchSize": 100 } }
        );

        cursor.on("data",function(item) {
          cursor.pause();
          console.log( "called" );
          db.update(
            { "_id": item._id },
            { "$inc": { "count": item.count } },
            { "upsert": true },
            function(err) {
              cursor.resume();
            }
          );
        });

        cursor.on("end",function() {
          console.log( "done" );
          db.find({},function(err,result) {
            callback(err,result);
          });
        });
      }

    ],
    function(err,result) {
      callback(err,result);
    }
  );

}

mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err,conn) {

  getCount(
    1000 * 60 * 60,                     // each hour
    new Date("2014-07-01").valueOf(),   // start
    new Date("2014-07-02").valueOf(),   // end
    function(err,result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log( result );
    }
  );

});
```

So essentially create each interval as in memory collection and then just update those interval records with the actual data retrieved. I can't think of another way to do that where it would be more simple and natural to the way of thinking.

Just a footnote, the "interval" logic is just replicated from your question, but in fact the time periods are "rounded up" where 15 minutes would appear in hour 1. It usually is the practice to round down so that everything belongs to the interval it falls in and not the next one.

Answer (score 0):

this is hacky fix I did for now:

```
var getCount = function(timeBlock, start, end, cb) {

    Document.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            time: {
                $gte: new Date(start),
                $lt: new Date(end)
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: 1,
            delta: { $subtract: [
                new Date(end),
                '$time'
            ]}
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: 1,
            delta: { $subtract: [
                "$delta",
                { $mod: [
                    "$delta",
                    timeBlock
                ]}
            ]}
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $subtract: [
                end,
                "$delta"
            ]},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            time: "$_id",
            count: 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    },

    {
        $sort: {
            time: 1
        }

    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            // really hacky way
            var numOfTimeBlocks = ( end - start ) / timeBlock

            // in case there is no 0s in the given period of time there is no need
            // to iterate through all of the results
            if ( results.length === numOfTimeBlocks ) {
                cb(results);

            } else {
                var time = start;
                var details = [];

                var times = results.map(function(item) {
                    return item.time;
                });

                for( var i = 0; i < numOfTimeBlocks; i++) {
                    time += timeBlock;
                    var idx = times.indexOf(time);

                    if (idx > -1) {
                        details.push(results[idx]);
                    } else {
                        var documentCount = { count: 0, time: time };
                        details.push(documentCount);
                    }
                }

                cb(details);
            }

        }
    })
}
```

I was also thinking about doing one query per time block, which gives the same result but I think is inefficient because you query the database N times.